# SQL Server SSIS increases number of digits when loading float field

Tags: csv, ssis, precision

I have a SSIS project which loads a csv file to an sqlserver table. While loading field with two decimal digits into a `float` column, it increases the number of digits and changes the column value.

As an example, the csv field value is `173.76`, but the table value is `173.759994506836`.

How can this happen?

CSV connection properties are;

- Locale : Turkish (Turkey)
- Code Page: 1252
- Data Type : float [DT_R4]

Comment: Don't use `FLOAT` in SQL Server - use `DECIMAL(p,s)` to have precise numbers.....

Comment: Thanks marc_s, i'll do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173773.aspx) datatype is an approximation. Either change your datatype to a more accurate one or - convert the value to nn.nnn during your import.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its my lack of knowledge about the floating point data type. Here is the definition from wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)